# what is query for this one?

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

[image]

I have a table with 3 columns `id`, `homeph`, `mobileph`.

If `homeph` is equal to `mobileph`, then `homeph` or `mobileph` with other line what is query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you could use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id, phone
FROM   input_table
UNPIVOT (
  phone FOR type IN (homeph, contactph) 
)
```

But it will be more efficient to check if the phone numbers are identical before unpivoting (as `UNPIVOT` will, by default, ignore `NULL` values):

```sql
SELECT id, phone
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         homeph,
         CASE WHEN homeph = contactph THEN NULL ELSE contactph END AS contactph
  FROM   input_table
)
UNPIVOT (
  phone FOR type IN (homeph, contactph) 
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE input_table (id, homeph, contactph ) AS
  SELECT 1, 99999, 88888 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 77777, 77777 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | PHONE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 99999 |
| 1 | 88888 |
| 2 | 77777 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IA83Ad55)

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the desired result.

```
SELECT ID AS id, Homeph AS phone
FROM table

UNION

SELECT ID AS id, Contactph AS phone
FROM table
```

Comment: Maybe for performance optimization, I would have to check the execution plan. But it is not mandatory, because of the `UNION`, it removes dublicates. You would need it with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: You are correct.  I saw UNION ALL not UNION as you have it